# JavaScript If else statement is not met

Tags: javascript, html

The problem is the if else statement is not met at updatediscountTotal() and after removing all the  item from the cart, the total is not return to 0.
Requirement:
i.  If the user order  
•   Between 5 - 10 products, 5% discount of total price.
•   More than 10 products, 15% discount of total price
ii. If the total price is larger than $100 then the postage fee is free. If it is not, then postage fee of $10 is applied.

```js
if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
} else {
    ready()
}

function ready() {
    var removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')
    for (var i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
        var button = removeCartItemButtons[i]
        button.addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
    }

    var quantityInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')
    for (var i = 0; i < quantityInputs.length; i++) {
        var input = quantityInputs[i]
        input.addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
    }

    var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-button')
    for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
        var button = addToCartButtons[i]
        button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked)
    }

    document.getElementsByClassName('btn-purchase')[0].addEventListener('click', purchaseClicked)
}

function purchaseClicked() {
    alert('Thank you for your purchase')
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    while (cartItems.hasChildNodes()) {
        cartItems.removeChild(cartItems.firstChild)
    }

    updatediscountTotal()
}

function removeCartItem(event) {
    var buttonClicked = event.target
    buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
  
    
    updatediscountTotal()
}

function quantityChanged(event) {
    var input = event.target
    if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value <= 0) {
        input.value = 1
    }

   
    updatediscountTotal()

}

function addToCartClicked(event) {
    var button = event.target
    var shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement
    var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-title')[0].innerText
    var price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-price')[0].innerText
    var imageSrc = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-image')[0].src
    addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc)
    
    updatediscountTotal()
}

function addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc) {
    var cartRow = document.createElement('div')
    cartRow.classList.add('cart-row')
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    var cartItemNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('cart-item-title')
    for (var i = 0; i < cartItemNames.length; i++) {
        if (cartItemNames[i].innerText == title) {
            alert('This item is already added to the cart')
            return
        }
    }
    var cartRowContents = `
        <div class="cart-item cart-column">
            <img class="cart-item-image" src="${imageSrc}" width="100" height="100">
            <span class="cart-item-title">${title}</span>
        </div>
        <span class="cart-price cart-column">${price}</span>
        <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
            <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="1">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">REMOVE</button>
        </div>`
    cartRow.innerHTML = cartRowContents
    cartItems.append(cartRow)
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')[0].addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0].addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
}

function updatediscountTotal() {
    var cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    var cartRows = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row')
    var total = 0
    countItem=0
    
    for (var i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
        var cartRow = cartRows[i]
        var priceElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0]
        var quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0]
        var price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('$', ''))
        var quantity = quantityElement.value
        total = total + (price * quantity)

        if (total<100){
            shipping=10
        
        }
    
        else{
            shipping=0
            }
    

       for (var j = 0; j < quantity.length; j++) { //to count item in every row
            var countItem = quantity[j]
            countItem+=quantity
        }

            if (countItem>5 || countItem<10) {
            discountprice=total*0.05
            discountedprice=total-discountprice+shipping}

            else if (countItem>10){
            discountprice=total*0.15
            discountedprice=total-discountprice+shipping}
 
    }

    shipping = Math.round(shipping * 100) / 100
    document.getElementsByClassName('cart-shipping-price')[0].innerText = '$' + shipping
    discountprice = Math.round(discountprice * 100) / 100
    document.getElementsByClassName('cart-discount-price')[0].innerText = '$' + discountprice
    subtotal = Math.round(total * 100) / 100
    document.getElementsByClassName('cart-subtotal-price')[0].innerText = '$' + total
    discountedprice = Math.round(discountedprice * 100) / 100
    document.getElementsByClassName('cart-total-price')[0].innerText = '$' + discountedprice
}
```

```html
<div><center><h1> ALL PRODUCT </h1></center></div>

<section class="container content-section">
  <h2 class="section-header">Hoodie & Jacket</h2>
  <div class="shop-items">
      <div class="shop-item">
          <span class="shop-item-title">Item1</span>
          <img class="shop-item-image" src="img/j1.jpg">
          <div class="shop-item-details">
              <span class="shop-item-price">$25.00</span>
              <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="shop-item">
          <span class="shop-item-title">Item2</span>
          <img class="shop-item-image" src="img/j2.jpg">
          <div class="shop-item-details">
              <span class="shop-item-price">$14.90</span>
              <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button"type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="shop-item">
          <span class="shop-item-title">Item3</span>
          <img class="shop-item-image" src="img/j3.jpg">
          <div class="shop-item-details">
              <span class="shop-item-price">$59.90</span>
              <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
          </div>
      </div>
      
  </div>

<section class="container content-section">
  <h2 class="section-header">CART</h2>
  <div class="cart-row">
      <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">ITEM</span>
      <span class="cart-price cart-header cart-column">PRICE</span>
      <span class="cart-quantity cart-header cart-column">QUANTITY</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cart-items">
  </div>
  <div class="cart-shipping">
      <strong class="cart-shipping-title">Shipping Fee</strong>
      <span class="cart-shipping-price">$0</span> <br>
  </div>
  <div class="cart-discount">
    <strong class="cart-discount-title">Discount</strong>
    <span class="cart-discount-price">$0</span><br>
</div>
<div class="cart-total">
  <strong class="cart-subtotal-title">SubTotal</strong>
  <span class="cart-subtotal-price">$0</span>
</div>
<div class="cart-total">
  <strong class="cart-total-title">Total</strong>
  <span class="cart-total-price">$0</span>
</div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-purchase" type="button">Purchase</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please see how to create an [mcve]. It’s very difficult for somebody to go through your entire code dump.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `if` condition:

```
           if (countItem>5 || countItem<10) {
```

EVERY number is either greater than 5 or less than 10.  You want `&&` here, not `||`.